# Strange behavior of Gather with DateObject

Tags: date-and-time, gathering

Using 13.3 I encountered the following.

```
l = {DateObject[{2021, 4, 27, 14, 35, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], DateObject[{2021, 4, 27, 14, 36, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], DateObject[{2021, 4, 27, 14, 36, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], DateObject[{2021, 4, 27, 14, 37, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.], DateObject[{2021, 4, 27, 14, 37, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.]}
```

To group same dates together the following command should work:

```
 Gather[l]
```

However it keeps all objects separates. Instead, the following works

```
 Gather[l, #1 == #2 &]
```

Which ought to be a synonym. Is there something I'm missing in how `Gather` works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the outputs of:

```
Gather[l, #1 === #2 &]

Gather[l, #1 == #2 &]
```

---

The default test is `SameQ` that translates to `#1===#2&`and this is what you are seeing. `Equal` does not mean the same. There is a decimal point following the `0` that alternates in the list entries.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a difference in the inputs, with the "seconds" being in one case an Integer and the other a Real. I just upgraded to 13.3 from 12.2 and I believe this code was working previously, so perhaps something changed slightly in the outputs, I'll need to figure out where.

Comment: I am on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: OK, that's interesting. In that case I don't know what could be the reason. Is there a way to easily convert the date formats or compare them in such a way they would be equal?

Comment: The variation `Gather[l, #1 == #2 &]` is already doing that, You have to write it expressly.

Comment: Indeed, I should have clarified my code is using GroupBy, to take advantage of the ```GroupBy[l, f->g]``` syntax, which then forces the ```===``` comparison.

Comment: A bit simpler notation: `Gather[l, Equal]`, or rationalizing the dates: `Gather[Rationalize[l]]`